# How for-each loop works?

Tags: java, loops, foreach

In the below code I am trying to print sentence in reverse. It works for me.

I am not understanding why it prints "seven" first and not "one".

As per my knowledge below in for-each loop means "words" in "list of words" i.e original and iterate. Then in the next statement "words" is first and then "reversed".

Why does it print "seven" first and not "one" as the index starts from 0? Why does the last index come first? Please correct me if I am getting it wrong.

Any help would be appreciated. Please see code below:

```
public class String_Reverse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String s = "one two three four five six seven";
        System.out.println(reverse(s)); // seven six five four three two one


    }

    public static String reverse(String str) {
        String reversed = "";
        String[] original = str.trim().split(" ");
        for(String words : original) {
            reversed = words + " " + reversed;
        }
        return reversed;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop itererations are as follows:

Before 1st iteration 
`reversed= ""`

1st Iteration : `words = "one"` and `reversed="one "`

2nd Iteration : `words = "two"` and `reversed="two one "`

3rd Iteration : `words = "three"` and `reversed="three two one "`

4th Iteration : `words = "four"` and `reversed="four three two one "`

5th Iteration : `words = "five"` and `reversed="five four three two one "`

6th Iteration : `words = "six"` and `reversed="six five four three two one "`

7th Iteration : `words = "seven"` and `reversed="seven six five four three two one  "`

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over the array in increasing order of the indices, so the last index doesn't come first.

However, you are creating the output by concatenating the current `String` to the intermediate result (created by the previous iteration).

For example, the first iterations produce the following:

```
"one" + " " + ""
"two" + " " + "one "
"three" +" " + "two one "
...
```

In the end, the last element "seven" is appended to "six five four three two one", so you end up with all the elements concatenated in reversed order.